# WordPress plugin development extended comment functionality

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin to enter fatalities (idk. if right translated I mean persons that died).

I want to add the function to light candles and write a text for every fatality. I thought on the WordPress comments i think this is exactly what I need. But the problem is, that I need this functionality two times. One time for the candles and one time for the 'guestbook-like' function.

Is it possible to customize the comment function to get two separate things? The candle function needs a text and a image that you can choose.

The 'guestbook-like' function need a name and a text.

Can you give me some hints for my plan or do you have other ideas?

Comment: Please explain properly by showing some of your code or work that you have done.

Comment: At the moment there is no code i want to plan everything before i start coding

Comment: Maybe you can try by adding your plan. Maybe some bullet points.